# Linear Regression with classification variables for prediction

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

The thing I want to do is estimating time 'ET', with relevant binary variables:
Data set looks like this. (It is based on Python Pandas)

To estimate time(ET), there are 3 different variables; season,timezone, and color.
I assume that 3 variables are related with ET.

[image]

With this data set, I would like to run Linear regression to estimate 'ET.'

I made a code, but it doesn't work.
Is it right method to apply linear regression on this code?

```
train_x = df.drop(["ET"], axis=1)
train_y = df["ET"]
test_x = test.drop(["ET"], axis=1)
test_y = test["ET"]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()

model.fit(train_x, train_y)

model.score(test_x, test_y)


check = lambda x : 'Negative relationship' if x<0 else 'Positive relationship'
for i in range(len(train_x.columns)):
    print('About %s, the coefficient value is %s , Waiting time is %s.'%(train_x.columns[i], model.coef_[i], check(model.coef_[i])))

(mse) = mean_squared_error(y_test, forcast)


print('constant term is %s.' % (model.intercept_))
print(mse) = mean_squared_error(y_test, prediction)
```

The result I want to get is a value of MSE, RMSE, and R^2 value.

Comment: I think you should look into detail on how to approach machine learning workflow. Just by looking on how you define test and train I see many mistakes.
I highly recommend following book https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.06-linear-regression.html

Comment: @SMS Thank you for information!

Comment: You need to remove one column of each category to avoid having correlated predictors (eg : Spring, Summer, Fall but not Winter for instance)

Also where does the `forcast` variable came from ?

Comment: @LuisBlanche I am sure 'forcast' is a typo of 'forecast'  which is the estimated value thorugh above linear regression method.

Comment: If `forecast` is not assigned anywhere it will not work. Here, I think there should be a line somewhere like this : `forecast = model.predict(test_y)` right after the model was fitted. More over I see you use `test_y` then `y_test` so this is not going to work either .